# Does drinking a potion permit an opportunity attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, opportunity-attack

I've seen a question on here before that mentioned drinking a potion opens up a character to an opportunity attack, but the question was referring to Pathfinder. Is this the case for DnD 5e?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No. Opportunity Attacks list one event that triggers them: When you move out of a creature's reach.

> Opportunity Attacks.
>
> In a fight, everyone is constantly watching for enemies to drop their guard. You can rarely move heedlessly past your foes without putting yourself in danger; doing so provokes an opportunity attack. You can make an opportunity attack when a hostile creature that you can see moves out of your reach. To make the opportunity attack, you use your reaction to make one melee attack against the provoking creature. The attack interrupts the provoking creature's movement, occurring right before the creature leaves your reach.
>
> -PHB p. 195. Basic p. 74

Some abilities can give a creature additional opportunities for opportunity attacks, such as Mage Slayer, which provides one when someone in reach casts a spell. But without an explicit exception (none of which currently exist for potions), drinking a potion will not trigger an opportunity attack.

Comment: Which to me sounds silly. To drink a potion in mid-combat, you need a free hand and at least part of your attention: pull out the flask, uncork it, put it to your mouth, drink it and get rid of the bottle. I don't think that you can do all of this while still keeping your attention to the fight.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs mechanics aren't intended to model realism, and in this case it's one of *numerous* abstractions that are made. 5e is designed to *not* worry too much about position or penalize you for taking most combat actions. The *only* thing that merits an OA is moving out of reach without disengaging. That's it. You could of course choose to have more things trigger one, but that would be the answer *For your game* not *in general* or *as written*

Comment: @Nate If this was 3.5e then your intuition would be right, but in 5e OAs don't represent distraction, they represent "movi[ng] heedlessly past your foes". For another explicit thing that demonstrates that 5e's OAs are not equivalent to 3.5e's except in name: firing a ranged weapon or casting a spell in an enemy's reach doesn't trigger an OA.